# SQL Server / Asp.net MVC Database Structure

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, ssms

I have to develop an application that registers children and associates this child with a parent. When the parent logs in, they will have to be redirected only for the information of their child.

I created a User and Function table. To Login, the User must have an associated function. I also created a table named Father, the parents being a User and associated with a child.

My question is whether it is worth keeping the Parent table .... or "introducing" parents as being Users. If you are a parent ... you have an associated child, but if you are an ordinary User or Administrator you may not have anyone associated with it.

Which form is most correct for the database?

[image]

Update DataBase
[UpDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w693o.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi there Usually what i go with these kind of project is the 3 tables setup

- User
- Role
- UserToRole

So User is as you know a basic user with login creds and things
now second the Roles table will have all the roles in your app 
meaning this table for you will have master values like

Student
Parent
Administrator
Teacher
etc

the 3rd User To Role will map the users with the roles

like userId - RoleId

this is a better approach less complicated and also easy to implement instead of having a 
Table separate for users,students etc you can have all users in same table and then 
map the user with the subsequent role

User Table

- Id

  - Username
  - Other fields

Roles table

- Id

  - Role
  - Description

UserToRoles Table

- Id

  - UserId
  - RoleId

Comment: Sounds great to me, but how connect between tables?

Comment: Well usertorole table will connect em

Comment: UserToRole table will have userid and the roleid assigned to that user

Comment: I connect the User To Role table to the Role table and to the User table, right?

Comment: Yep..that's what I am sayiy

Comment: I'm all confused. Can you tell me what ID's I should have on each table?

Comment: Will I need to put IDUserToRole in the User table?

Comment: No why would you do that

Comment: In the question, I introduced an image of the new database. Is that correct, right?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to crete `ParentTable` separately, You Can Add another column in user table as "`IsParent`" which will identify if the user is parent or a normal user.